# "Every rational function of a complex number $z = x + iy$ is a rational function of $x$ and $y$, but not the other way around"

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from the page 19 of the book called *An Introduction to Complex Function Theory* by Bruce P. Palka.

> Every rational function of $z = x + iy$ is clearly a rational function of $x$ and $y$, but not the other way around.

As a reminder, a rational function of $z = x + iy$ is defined as $f(z) = \frac{a_0 + a_1z + \dots + a_n z^n}{b_0 + b_1 z + \dots b_m z^m}$. I understand the first part of the claim: if $z$ is fixed, i.e. both $x$ and $y$ are fixed, then of course all combinations of $a$s and $b$s are part of the set where $a$s, $b$s, $x$s and $y$s can vary. But I don't see why this wouldn't hold the other way around. Specifically, why cannot we choose the coefficients $a_0,\dots,a_n$ and $b_0,\dots,b_m$ in such a way that any change in $x$ or $y$ is mitigated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take for example the function $f(z)=x$, the real part of $z$. Then $f$ is a rational function of $x$ but not of $z$ since
$$f(z)=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}.$$
On the other hand, we may say that every rational function of $x$ and $y$ is a rational function of $z$ and $\overline{z}$ and the other way around because
$$\begin{cases}
z=x+iy\\
\overline{z}=x-iy
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}x=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}\\ y=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}\end{cases}$$

Comment: So the reason why $f$ isn't a rational function of $z$ is because the fraction contains also the conjugate of $z$?

Comment: @Epsilon Away Yes, exactly.